# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion

[What are the odds, Split pot 7 card stud between Royal flushes?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11529/what-are-the-odds-split-pot-7-card-stud-between-royal-flushes)

The reason given it was Closed. "This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers."

> Title: What are the odds, Split pot 7 card stud between Royal flushes?
>
> Body: It is rumored to have happened by a dealer named Al Bass, a few decades ago at the Sahara.

What further detail is needed to answer this question? What is not clear about the question?

Comment: Perhaps @radu-murzea can elaborate? I assume you thought the question or the way it's phrased wasn't clear enough when you closed it. fyi, feel free to edit it if you think it would help (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

Answer (score 1):

I closed it because it lacks any details whatsoever. For me at least, it it took 3 - 4 readings before I could understand what was asked.

If you add some details in the question body, for me it's fine to re-open ;)

Comment: Really, what detail would you like to see? Seriously Radu, it is a simple question. What are the odds of a two royal flushes in one hand of stud? You may not be able to come up with anymore detail, because there is none.

Comment: Just seeing this now, but for me I can see where Radu is coming from, but I do agree with Jon and that to me this question makes sense. Perhaps as a suggestion, adding the title to the body would be enough. I know some people just click into questions and forget to read the title so no harm to include the title in the question imo. I'm pro opening this question up again.

Comment: As a suggestion for the body. "I'm wondering what the probability of two royal flushes in 7 card stud occurring in the same hand, causing a split pot. It is rumored to have happened by a dealer named Al Bass, a few decades ago at the Sahara."